# We don't need to stop running project due to server side datas changes

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, uibinder, gwt-rpc, gwt2

How to do server side datas changes may be effect or update by browser's refresh in GWT projects ? Browsers may download js files of client side , but not server side. When a project is bigger and bigger , that may consumes many times of us. We also wait js files downloading times. One or two times were not problem. But if we changes small things and we want to see it's effects urgently , we will stop server again , re-run the project again , wait js file downloading time , reLogin again and so on. So , I really want to know how to do. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks for reading my question patiently...

Comment: Is Server side and Client side code is in single project or different projects

Comment: May be diff or same .If also same , server side datas still not effected after update.

Comment: We must compile our Server side code,before app runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a "Restart Server" button in the DevMode window (in the Google Plugin for Eclipse it's a pair or swirling yellow arrows).

It'll restart the webapp, reloading the compiled classes from `WEB-INF/classes` and JARs from `WEB-INF/lib`.
If you're using Eclipse, it should already be configured to compile classes to that `WEB-INF/classes` folder so it should Just Work™.

Comment: Wow ! it is really work ... AWESOME !!! Thanks bro. I want to know will it be recompile or revalidate xml , properties files ?

Comment: Please describe more about it with kindfully bro!

Comment: It just undeploys and redeploys the webapp, just as if you had restarted the DevMode. It doesn't recompile though, only reloads (what your IDE would have already compiled on-the-fly, generally).

Answer (score 1):

My problem can solved with [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/blog/how-to-rock-out-with-jrebel-and-google-web-toolkit-gwt/) but I want to know is another way because it is not free tool :) .

It is awesome tool. You can add it your eclipse as plugin and add it's nature. If you run your project with it's console you can get always update datas of client and server side datas by saving your class or xml or any other files (I mean as I know ). If you want to test with it , guide is here..
[JRebel for Eclipse](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/installing-jrebel-plugin-for-eclipse/) 
That may be helpful for you...

Answer (score 0):

To see the immediate changes you can **copy** your js files and **paste** it in your target folder of entrypoint project. And a browser refresh will suffice. Sometimes clearing of browser cache also required.

This might not be a classy solution but it will reflect the changes and in cases where you don't want to restart the server again and again to check whether it works or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but I mean server side codes , not client side datas. Client side datas will be update as the browser refresh. I want to do server side data also. JS files may represent client side datas.